# Sensitivity label value for PDF documents not showing in SharePoint Online library

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, column, sharepoint-library, dlp

I have sensitivity labels enabled for my Office 365 tenant and have created labels, policies as well as some DLP rules. All appears to be working correctly in SharePoint libraries, apart from PDF documents.

[image: SharePoint library with sensitivity column]

The DLP policy sign is showing for the PDF document, but the value of the sensitivity label is blank.
I labelled the document on my machine using the AIP Unified client and then uploaded the file (as I did with the visio file) I have tried searching for the value of the tag using search format of InformationProtectionLabelId:[label_guid] but the PDF document's sensitivity label value doesn't show. I have also re-indexed the library.

Is this by default? Is it the case that all non Office documents sensitivity label value is not displayed?

Any idea if there is a workaround? Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Can you check the document properties for an Office file and a non-Office file?
Use
https://.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='///')/properties

This will return an XML response. Check if the sensitivity is present for both file types.

Paul

Comment: Very useful tip. Thanks for this. I have now tried this. I can see the sensitivity value for Office docs and the vision file. The guids returned match the guids for the label values, so that's all good. There is no sensitivity label value there for the PDF document, so I am assuming that non Office documents are not supported at the moment?

Comment: Cool. "a sensitivity label is stored as clear text in the metadata of a document" see
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/sensitivity-labels?view=o365-worldwide

This may explain why it is working fine for Office files and not in your PDF file.

Some common formats where it should work:
docx, xlsx, pptx, vsdx, tiff, ...

Some common formats where it does not work:
pdf, msg, jpg, eml, zip

Answer (score 0):

Chris,
How'd you go with this behavior, of PDF's not displaying their sensitivity labels.
I've arrived at very much the same findings as you.
I've researched to see if there are some sort of indexing or timer job that runs and picks these up but nothing has come up.
What did you learn.